# how to apply on click action on menu in android?

Tags: android

how to apply on click action on menu in android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(Menu.Item item) {
    // here you can do a switch on item ID, to apply different actions for different menu items
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try implementing onMenuItemClickListener to the MenuItem selected.

See the doc of [MenuItem](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html)